# Java: How do I write a "Hang-man" game?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

So I've arranged an array of char's making up a word.
The user will be asked to input a certain letter.
If this letter is in the word (array), it will display the input letter on the correct place in the array, surrounded by "-" signs, and keep asking for a letter. This is my code so far:

```
Scanner A = new Scanner(System.in);
    char [] woord = {'a','p','e','n','h','o','o','f','d'};

    int totaal=0;

    while (totaal < 10){

        System.out.println("Voer een letter in");
        char letter = A.nextLine().charAt(0);

        for (int teller = 0; teller < woord.length; teller++){

            if (woord[teller] == letter){
                System.out.print(" "+letter+" ");
                totaal++;
            }

            if (woord[teller] != letter){
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
```

Now I need to create a loop that keeps on asking the user for letters and once another letter is guessed correctly it will fill in another place in the array, until all the "-" signs have become letters and the entire word has been guessed. The current loop will only show the guessed letter and not display previously correctly guessed letters. Any tips?

Comment: You need to keep a list of "guesses", so that each time you print the output, you know which letters have been previous guessed

Comment: Any tips on how to do that so it will still display it in the correct position?

Comment: Well, your basic loop at the moment is working, expect, rather then using the "last" guess you need to use all the "previous" guesses.  This might require a second, inner loop to achieve

Comment: Thanks, I will most certain try that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Try [java scanner](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-stdin-and-stdout-1/problem).